# Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0. error in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to connect firebase to my application.
after pressing "Add firebase authentication to your app" Im getting the following error:" Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0"
That leads me to the dependencies in build.gradle(module:app).
the error:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

the details on the error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

My entire dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

Comment: The latest version of Firebase Authentication is 16.0.5. Helpful hint: any dependencies highlighted in yellow are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In your root-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

In your module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

    // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
    // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```